# Reproduce random DAG generated with dagitty::randomDAG()

Tags: javascript, r, directed-acyclic-graphs, random-seed

I am using `dagitty::randomDAG()` to generate random directed acyclic graphs (DAGs). I would like to be able to reproduce the *same* random DAG but `randomDAG()` doesn't seem to respect the random seed in R.

For example, the following code produces a different random DAG on each run:

```
set.seed(1234)
dagitty::randomDAG(4, .5)
```

`dagitty::randomDAG` calls some JS code and I suspect those JS functions are using a different random seed, not the random seed in R. So I wonder if a solution would be to fix whatever seed those JS functions defer to, but not sure how I would go about that.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky solution to this: use the `randomDag()` function from the `pcalg` package, which does respond to the random seed. Then a bit of manipulation to revert to `dagitty` syntax

```
library(pcalg)

set.seed(1234)

p1 <- randomDAG(n = 4, prob = .5)
p2 <- as(p1, "matrix")
p3 <- pcalg2dagitty(p2, labels = paste0('x', 1:5))
gsub('pdag', 'dag', p3)
```